# Android RecyclreView OnCLick Listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Error on android recyclerView Adapter. App will stop working while click on RecyclerView items. I want to go other activity when click any items, when i'm using Toast it working fine but if i add Intent then it stop working.

Here is my Interface :

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

here is my recycler Adapter calss :

```
public class RecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Items> items;
    private Context context;

    public RecAdapter(List<Items> items, Context context )
    {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)  {

        holder.countryname.setText(items.get(position).getCountryname());
        holder.rank.setText(items.get(position).getRank());
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(items.get(position).getFlag())
                .into(holder.flag);
        holder.setClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context , Main2Activity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView countryname, rank;
        ImageView flag;
        private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            countryname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.capital);
            rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            itemView.setTag(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        public void setClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
        }
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: *`Error on android recyclerView Adpter class`* What error?

Comment: this is because the `context` is `NULL` ...also, `onBindViewHolder` has a whole another responsibility, than what you are trying to accomplish there.

Comment: Formatted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add click listener like this:-

```
View itemView;
Context context;


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    this.context=parent.getContext();
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context , Main2Activity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not click an holder directly..... give a id to the view then re write the code as below:

```
holder.(someitem).setClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {//you need a view to execute the onclicklistener
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context , Main2Activity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

copying an answer of mine from a different question:

as you already know this method is no longer available in the `RecyclerView` class.

My approach towards implementing `onClick` events in a `RecyclerView` is something like this:

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    interface OnClickListener {
        void onClick(Item item);
    }

    private final List<Item> dataset;
    private final OnClickListener l; 

    public MyAdapter(List<Item> data, OnClickListener listener) {
        this.dataset = data;
        this.l = listener;
    }

    @Override MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = //inflate layout
        MyClick click = new MyClick() {
            onClick(int position) {
                if (l != null) {
                    l.onClick(dataset.get(position));
                }
            }
        };
        return new MyViewHolder(click, v);
    }

    static class MyViewHolder {
        final MyClick l;

        public MyViewHolder(MyClick listener, View view) {
            super(view);
            l = listener;
            // inflate views
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                if (l != null) {
                    l.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

        interface MyClick {
            void onClick(int position);
        }
    }
}

class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set layout
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getData(), new OnClickListener() {
            @Override onClick(Item item) {
                // do stuff with item
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which i create click listener for **Recycler Item Click**

Using this you will get two types of click

1. Simple Item click.
2. Item Long click.

**Here is RecyclerItemClickListener.java File**

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener  implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
public interface OnItemClickListener
{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
}

private OnItemClickListener mListener;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener)
{
    mListener = listener;

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
        {
            View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if(childView != null && mListener != null)
            {
                mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildPosition(childView));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e)
{
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

    if(childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))
    {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent){}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

}

**How to use in Activity and Fragment**

```
  rvcyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, rvcyclerView,
                new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //do you what you want tot do simple click
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                        //do you what you want tot do on long click
                    }
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private List<Items> items;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

    public RecAdapter(List<Items> items, Context context )
    {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)  {

        holder.countryname.setText(items.get(position).getCountryname());
        holder.rank.setText(items.get(position).getRank());
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(items.get(position).getFlag())
                .into(holder.flag);
        holder.flag.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView countryname, rank;
        ImageView flag;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            countryname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.capital);
            rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        }

            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }    
    }
}
```

On Your Activity / Fragment Implement OnItemClickListener

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayoutManager layout = new 
            LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout );
            mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            RecAdapter adapter = new RecAdapter(items ,getContext());
            adapter.setClickListener(this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter );
        }

     @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
       switch(view.getId()) {
       }
 }
```

}